# why can't pattern matching share where clauses?

Tags: haskell, syntax, scope, pattern-matching

I wrote this and it does not compile

```
import Data.Maybe
func Nothing Nothing = func2 "hello" "world"
func x       y       = func2 "hello" "world"
  where func2 a b = a ++ b
main = print $ func Nothing Nothing
```

> ```
> test.hs:2:24: error:
>     • Variable not in scope: func2 :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
>     • Perhaps you meant ‘func’ (line 2)
> ```

I rewrote it by using guards and it worked. But I would like to know why it is like this.

Comment: `where` clauses only apply to a single pattern match case.  (Though it can apply to multiple guards in a single case)

Comment: It's clearly insufficient merely to say what the rules are. Why are those the rules? Well, in the definition of `func2`, the variables `x` and `y` are in scope. The scope of the `where` is not determined by what gets used, and the presumption is that different clauses will have different pattern variables, hence different scopes, so there's no reason to believe sharing `where` clauses will make sense. Pattern matching is a rather flattened way to manage hierarchichal decision processes: the `where` notation gives split-then-make-helper, but, yes, make-helper-then-split can sometimes be good.

Comment: And importantly, if you want make-helper-then-split you don't need `where`, you can just define a new top-level function, or use a `let` if you're closing over some locals. As is, you have access to both options; if `where` shared patterns, you could only write shared bindings.

Comment: Think about what you wrote. It's the same thing as writing: `func Nothing Nothing = func2 "hello" "world"; func x y = let func2 a b = a ++ b in func2 "hello" "world"`. Why do you expect the `let` binding to be valid in the first equation? Every single patter-case is a *separate* definition. If you want shared local definitions you have to do something like `func x y = case (x, y) of (Nothing, Nothing) -> ...; (_,_) -> ... where func2 a b = a ++b`, i.e. have the top-level function use a single catch-all match and use a `case` for the actual pattern matching.